# React: why is a correct file path throwing a'module not found' error when being mapped?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that is supposed to be populated with an image through mapping it with *item.portrait* and *item.smallportra*it

```
              <figure className="rounded-sm">
           <ProgressiveImage delay={3000} src={require(item.portrait).default} placeholder={require(item.smallportrait).default} >
  {src => <img src={src} alt="DS" width="416" height="582" className="inset-0  object-cover transform hover:scale-105 transition duration-700 ease-out" />}
  </ProgressiveImage>

  
    </figure>
            <h3 className="h4 mb-2">{item.name}</h3>
            <p className="text-lg text-gray-500 flex-grow">{item.title}</p>
            </Link>
            </div>
```

The date passed into the component is in this structure, and the path to the respective images is also correct (triple checked)

```
    {
id: '1',  
link: 'john-doe',
name: 'John Doe',
alt: 'John Doe',
portrait: '../images/john_doe.png',
smallportrait: '../images/john_doe_small.jpg',
title: 'Managing Director',
bio: 'works with retail and consumer-goods companies to guide growth, commercial and operational transformations'} 
},
```

But I'm getting a *Cannot find module './../images/team/john_doe.png'* error every time.

How can this happen when the file path to the image is 100% correct and all other mapping items are mapped correctly and functioning?

Comment: Rather than opening a new question, it would be advisable to add details to the closed one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68286042/react-correct-syntax-for-mapping-data-in-a-component) and await for it to be re-opened.

Comment: Since that question was closed under false premises, maybe by accident, there is no possibility for me to rephrase, edit or supplement it in a way that would justify a re-opening.

Comment: You're using a relative path. Are you sure it's correct? Is it relative from your build directory or where the React component is located?

Comment: Why do you say it was closed under "false premises"? The issue is actually not reproducible with the information you provided in the question. For what concerns editing it, you just have to click on the button [Improve this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68286042/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was ultimately solved by importing the image in the data.js file :

```
import JohneDoe from '../src/images/john_doe.png';        
        
        
export const TeamData = [ 



{
    id: '1',  
    link: 'john-doe',
    name: 'John Doe',
    alt: 'John Doe',
    portrait: JohnDoe,
    title: 'Managing Director',
    bio: 'works with retail and consumer-goods companies to guide growth, commercial and operational transformations'} 
    },
```

Code Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-silence-bkyfl?file=/src/index.js